# Characteristic polynomial and characteristic equation

Tags: matrices

What is the major difference between the characteristic polynomial and the characteristic equation?

Comment: One is just the polynomial not set equal to anything. The equation is when you set it equal to zero to find the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic equation sets the characteristic polynomial equal to $0$.  In symbols, if the characteristic polynomial is $p(x)$, then the characteristic equation is the equation $p(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

the characteristic polynomial is determinant of the matrix(A-&I) where, & is an igenvector and I is an identity matrix, whereas the characteristic equation is the characteristic polynomial equated to zero.